# Calling Google Contacts API through OAuth 2.0 service account gives AuthenticationException

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api, gdata-api

Here's the code I have been working on:

```
public String getGoogleContact(String queryStr) throws
    AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException,
    ServiceException, GeneralSecurityException{

        String emailAddress = "something@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        String path = "src/main/resources/key.p12";

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                                    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                                    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
                                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(path))
                                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"))
                                    .setServiceAccountUser("myEmail@example.com").build();

        ContactsService service = new ContactsService("MYAPP");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        Query myQuery = new Query( new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"));
        myQuery.setFullTextQuery(queryStr);
        ContactFeed resultFeed = service.query(myQuery, ContactFeed.class);
        String result = "";

       for (ContactEntry entry : resultFeed.getEntries()) {
           result += entry.getTitle().getPlainText();
       }

       return result;
    }
```

And I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
>   at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.(AuthenticationException.java:67) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1237) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]
>   at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1178) ~[core-1.47.1.jar:na]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this workaround to your ContactsService init block

```
service.getRequestFactory().setHeader("User-Agent", applicationName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still get a different exception this time:

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92) ~[google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectPa...

Comment: I use same code as yours, but mine uses "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full" as scopes.